# Efficient way to recognise an unchanged directory

Tags: python, python-3.5, checksum, directory-structure, os.walk

Is there a way to efficiently avoid that os.walk enters a branch of a directory tree which has not been changed since a previous os.walk?

I'm scanning contents of a filesystem with a custom Python application and storing technical data generated from the contents and storing it in a database. The file system is large and the scanning process takes more than 4 hours currently so I am looking for a way to recognise dynamically which branches/directories of the filesystem do not need to be re-scanned (because there have been no changes and the data already exists).

I've been investigating storing a directory checksum in the database and before actually processing any directory, running a current checksum to see if any of the subfolders have seen changes. However running the current checksum takes a  long time - maybe as much as the the current "scan everything" approach.

I've seen packages like [Watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html#quickstart) which essentially run a continuous scan back and forth, however as this filesystem is so large, it could take a long (and unknown) time (maybe 10+ hours) to actually see the database updated.

Comment: I'm going to try a different solution : Using the windows lastModified metadata present in every directory which is updated when a file is added, removed or changed within it (but not its subdirectories). "os.path.getmtime(dirpath)" retrieves the last modified metadata which would need recorded in the DB for future comparison. This operation looks to be fast and light and it might be a viable option to save the heavy duty scanning in a large portion of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use "os.path.getmtime(dirpath)" to add a record for the directory scan status. By pulling this record before scanning the directory I can check whether it has already been scanned and if it has been scanned whether or not there been a change to the directory since it was done. Only files in new or modified directories are scanned now.